# Unable to run macros in dotm files on other PCs

Tags: vba, ms-word

Macros created and updated to .dotm files work well on the creator's PC, but when distributed to other users they do not work (run).

1. Tried and double-checked the Trust center settings on MS Word: Macro setting is 'Enable all macros'. Ensured that the location the ("%appdata%\Microsoft\Word\Startup") is already a Trusted Location.
2. Ensured that all the check points mentioned in this [link](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_other/the-macro-cannot-be-found-or-has-been-disabled/58c67454-235a-4d24-a77a-10e6995aca04) are as expected.

The code is created following this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2010/gg597509(v=office.14)):

While the VBA add-in gets recognized, when I click on the add-in button the macro does not run. I suspected that the macro code was getting deleted, since I distributed the .dotm files over email. So, I password protected and zipped them, still the same error.

The error message I am getting is the following:

> The macro cannot be found or has been disabled because of your Macro
>   Security settings

[image]

I would like to be able to run the macro on other PCs as well.

**Update**
I noticed that the macros, I created were not listed in my PC as well. Now, additionally I did the following change.

```
Public Sub export_main()
    Call export_helper
End Sub
```

where,

```
Public Sub export_helper (ByVal control As IRibbonControl)
 'do stuff
End Sub
```

With this the macro was getting listed in other PC as well. Since, I did not pass the control value expected for the function `export_helper` from `export_main`, the macro threw an error, saying arguments are not supplied. How do I fix this without getting the argument in `export_main`. Since VBA seems to be expecting a function with no arguments to be listed in the macros window (am not sure if this is right.)

Comment: Go to the View tab and at the right click the Macros button. Select the template name from the "Macros in" list. Do you see the macro in the list? If yes, and you select it then click "Run" does it run? If yes, then the problem is in the connection between the macro and the "button". If that is the case, please use the [edit] link below the question to add the *exact steps* used to create the "button" *in the question itself*. (Might be a good idea to execute the steps as you write, to be sure this is exactly what you're doing.)

Comment: Hello Cindy, I just noticed that the macro is not listed in even in my PC (Creator of the macro). I am able to run it from the custom button on the ribbon though. The button was created as I indicated using the VBA add-in tutorial link given in the question. Look for the heading "To add customUI markup to an Office 2010 document or template". Giving it here for quick reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2010/gg597509(v=office.14)

Comment: Update: Ok, I followed your other answer and moved the code manually to  the template project. Shared the updated .dotm file to other PC, still the same error.

Comment: I updated the original question to include what changes I did. Please help.

Comment: Please remember to "ping" using the @ symbol before the person's name whom you want to address. Otherwise, there will be no notification and it will seem to you that you're being ignored.

Comment: The update to the question doesn't help, a lot - there's too little information about exactly what you've done. Everything relevant to a question needs to be *in the question*, not linked. You need to provide a clear, concise [mcve] so that we know exactly what you've done. From the last code snippet it's clear that the macro won't appear in any list as it's supposed to be linked to a Ribbon control. Is the code in the same file as the Ribbon UI definition? Show us the Ribbon XML.

Comment: @CindyMeister: Apologies for not replying earlier and my unclear question. The latest situation is that, I am able to list the macro n other PCs as well and run them too from the ribbon. My only doubt remains as to, if there is a macro sub which takes parameters, then it will not be listed in the macro window?

Comment: That is correct, Deepak. Passing parameters assumes the user needs to provide such information, otherwise the parameters would be known and wouldn't need to be passed to the procedure. You can attach the Ribbon controls to a different macro, that doesn't require parameters, and that, in turn, can call the procedure that does (and pass parameters). It could also provide an interface for user input, if that would be appropriate...

Comment: @CindyMeister Thank you for your response. I understood your explanation. I was able to resolve this issue as you said above. Appreciate your time for this question!